# How to implement error: in $('#sampleformid').ajaxForm plugin

Tags: jquery, ajaxform

I am using jquery's ajaxForm technique to upload files and i am using the below code for makin an ajax request to my servlet.

In below code the error functionality is not working

```
$("#form2").ajaxForm({
       url:'userImage.action',
       success: function() {
            alert("success");
        },
        data: {
            key1: value1,
            key2: value2
        }, 
        complete: function(xhr) {
            status.html(xhr.responseText);
        }
        error: function(xhr){
            alert("errorr");
        }
   }).submit();
```

Please help,

Comment: what do you mean by *error functionality not working*?

Comment: if use error: in the above code, the request is not raised, if i remove error: it is working fine.

Comment: Hi Amit thanks for the reply, and i solved it myself, as i have implemented error: before complete: